# Make a bash script run another file in Debian

Tags: bash, debian, steam

I've finished installing a Team Fortress 2 server on my Debian server, and I'd like to create a bash script to start my server without having to run `./srcds_run -game tf -maxplayers 32` every time I want to start it. This file is located in `/home/steam/orangebox`.

I've tried created a bash script (named `run.sh`) like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
/home/steam/orangebox/./srcds_run -game tf -maxplayers 32
```

and I've done `chmod -x run.sh` and tried to run it, but when I run it, I get `bash: ./run.sh: Permission denied` returned.

What do I need to change to make this bash script work?

Comment: You mean `chmod +x run.sh`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have the rights to run it..

```
#!/bin/bash
/home/steam/orangebox/srcds_run -game tf -maxplayers 32
```

A single . is used for the current directory, .. for a level up, etc. There is no need to add it when you are using the full path.

If interested, some additional information on the dot commands can be found [here](http://www.linfo.org/dot_slash.html).

Comment: Oh wow, I feel silly for not figuring that out. It works great now! Thank you!